# Highcharts Pie chart not accepting values

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, format

I'm using JavaScript to format the `y` values of a piechart to two decimal places but they are not appearing on the chart.

I need to take the percentage of each and then return them. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng1kvmxh/4/)

If the fiddle doesn't work this is my code.

```
$(function () {
      var dataPie =[];
    var abc =[{"val":"19981","name":"TOTAL"},{"val":"2051","name":"\"NATURAL GAS\""},{"val":"274","name":"\"OTHER FOSSIL FUELS\""},{"val":"8826","name":"\"DUAL FUEL\""},{"val":"5351","name":"\"NUCLEAR\""},{"val":"2628","name":"\"HYDRO\""},{"val":"501","name":"\"WIND\""},{"val":"350","name":"\"OTHER RENEWABLES\""},{"val":" ","name":"\"UNKNOWN\" "}];
 $.each(abc,function(i,el)
{
     var total = null;
     if(el.name == "TOTAL"){
            total = parseInt(el.val);
        }else{
            var p = parseInt(el.val) / total * 100;
            dataPie.push({name :el.name,y: p});
        }

});
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: { 
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Brands",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: dataPie
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: **I need to take the percentage of each** in the question is confusing...

Comment: you are formatting value with percentage upto 2 decimal point, but highcharts is capable to do that. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

highcharts is capable to do that ,you need to simply use

```
 {point.percentage:.2f}
```

See the fiddle, which has your last question's data updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ng1kvmxh/1/)

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the updates. The fiddle might not work, but I am trying to grab the percentages calculated from the total. I already had the format label

Comment: I mean to say , you don't need to calculate percentage, highcharts can do that. see my fiddle its working properly  http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ng1kvmxh/1/

Comment: Ok thanks. I still don't understand why my data isn't coming through on the graph

Comment: Becasuse , in the else case total is undefined ,which is returning infinity when you divide. Better to remove the total part from your json  if you don't want to remove that, you should check that else condition to make your code work.

Comment: The blank value in the UNKNOWN was throwing everything off. Also you don't need to calculate the percentages. Highcharts adds the values and figures that out on its own (which I did not know).

Comment: Yes, That's what I said... you don't need to calculate % highcharts does it well

Comment: blank value in unknown... was set as "null" in data pie I saw that in console        .... the data is working which is   [{"name":"\"NATURAL GAS\"","y":10.264751513938242},{"name":"\"OTHER FOSSIL FUELS\"","y":1.3713027376007207},{"name":"\"DUAL FUEL\"","y":44.17196336519694},{"name":"\"NUCLEAR\"","y":26.78044141934838},{"name":"\"HYDRO\"","y":13.152494870126622},{"name":"\"WIND\"","y":2.5073820129122666},{"name":"\"OTHER RENEWABLES\"","y":1.7516640808768331},{"name":"\"UNKNOWN\" ","y":null}]